# paint method with BreezyGUI flickering [Java]

Tags: java, graphics, paint, keylistener, repaint

Before anyone says this has been answered, I couldn't find this anywhere, because i'm not using buffered images, im using g.drawRect(...) and so on... to draw my object, this is what I was told to do because i'm learning how to code right now. But for some reason, the screen keeps flickering, and I would like some help.

So, i'm pretty new at coding, And I am trying to code a very simple bomberman game. And I'm not using BufferedImages, i'm just using Graphics paint, to draw the character. And, when I'm adding the KeyBinding, I use repaint() to "update" the game when a key is pressed. But this is very buggy and it glitches and shows a blank screen when I hold down one of the buttons. I think this is due to me repainting it, but i'm not sure of how to go about fixing this. Here is some of the code I am using.

```
    public static void left(Graphics g) {
    bomberManLowerLeft(g, -90 + dx, -20 + dy);
    bomberManBodyLeft(g, -90 + dx, -20 + dy);
    bomberManFaceLeft(g, -90 + dx, -20 + dy);
}

public static void right(Graphics g) {
    bomberManLowerRight(g, -90 + dx, -20 + dy);
    bomberManBodyRight(g, -90 + dx, -20 + dy);
    bomberManFaceRight(g, -90 + dx, -20 + dy);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (down) {
        front(g);
    } else if (up) {
        back(g);
    } else if (left) {
        left(g);
    } else if (right) {
        right(g);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frm = new BomberMan();
    frm.setSize(750, 750);
    frm.setVisible(true);
    frm.add(panel);
    frm.setBackground(Color.black);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int kCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (kCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        System.out.println("Right");
        dx += 3;
        down = false;
        right = true;
        left = false;
        up = false;
        repaint();
    } else if (kCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        System.out.println("Left");
        dx -= 3;
        down = false;
        right = false;
        left = true;
        up = false;
        repaint();
    } else if (kCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        System.out.println("Up");
        dy -= 3;
        down = false;
        right = false;
        left = false;
        up = true;
        repaint();
    } else if (kCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        System.out.println("Down");
        dy += 3;
        down = true;
        right = false;
        left = false;
        up = false;
        repaint();
    } else if(kCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        placeBomb = true;
        bombdx = dx;
        bombdy = dy;
        repaint();
    }

}
```

I could really use some help with this, thanks. And if you do need the full code here it is: [PASTEBIN-CODE](http://pastebin.com/HFWdHBaA)

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid extending directly from top level containers like `JFrame` (I don't know what `GBFrame` is, but I'm guess it derives from `JFrame` or some other window)
2. Avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, they aren't double buffered and if you break the paint chain (which you have), it can cause no end of issues.
3. Avoid `KeyListener`, it has to many issues with regards to focus and can easily become unresponsive.  Instead, consider using the key bindings API.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.
4. Avoid over use of `static`.  `static` is not a cross object communication mechanism and will cause no end of issues as your program becomes more complex.

Instead, create a custom component that extends from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting there...

```
public class BomberManPanel extends JPanel {
    //...
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Your painting goes here...
    }
}
```

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

I'd also move all your core logic to this component and simply add an instance of it to your `BomberMan` frame.

While your current approach will generally work, normally, you would have some kind of "game loop" which was responsible for updating the current state of the game and scheduling the rendering of the game state.

This means that instead of modifying the state within your key listener, you would simply set a flag, indicating which keys were currently pressed and allow the "game loop" to update the state accoridingly

In this case, you could simply use something like [a Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)